# Meaning of "File is not `gci`-ed with --skip-generated -s standard,default (gci)"

Tags: go, golint

I get this error message:

```
main.go:24: File is not `gci`-ed with --skip-generated -s standard,default (gci)
import (
```

What does this mean?

Background: I am new to Go, and the linting was not set up by me. I confess that I don't know the actual linter which creates this warning.

Comment: Looks like you are using a tool called `gci` which is skipping that file with the given flags. This isn't part of the `go` toolchain or language.

Comment: «I get this error message»—how do you get one? What linter do you run? It _looks_ like you're running `golangci-lint` (it aggregates multiple linters, and print the name of the linter which generated a warning in paretheses), is it correct? Please do not force those who's about to help to do psychic debugging.

Comment: If it's `golangci-lint`, then [here are the GCI's docs](https://github.com/daixiang0/gci) and [this](https://golangci-lint.run/usage/configuration) explains how to tweaks settings of particular linters or exclude specific files from being linted by particular linters etc.

Comment: @kostix thank you for your comments. I found a solution and posted it as answer below.

Comment: It is an issue that occurred because lint did not fit somewhere. In the case of me, I removed the blank line and solved it

Answer (score 23):

Try

```
golangci-lint run --fix
```

and you can go from there!

Comment: It might fix the issue but does not answer the question nor provide any hint. The answer from @guettli helped me understand the message and how to deal with the matter. I would recommend to understand what is going on before using the `--fix` option.

Comment: Installation instructions are here: https://golangci-lint.run/usage/install/#local-installation (Assuming, like me, you're getting this error from CI and want to run this locally!)

Answer (score 11):

[gci](https://github.com/daixiang0/gci) is

> a tool that controls golang package import order and makes it always deterministic.

When linting the code with [golangci-lint](https://golangci-lint.run/usage/linters/), the changes required by the [gci](https://github.com/daixiang0/gci) linter are not directly applied. One then has to manually apply them. For this get `gci` with

```bash
 go install github.com/daixiang0/gci@latest
```

scan it and directly write required changes with

```bash
gci write --skip-generated -s standard,default .
```

- `--skip-generated` skips generated files
- `-s standard,default` defines how import inputs are processed. `standard` are all official Golang provided imports, `default` are all other ones.

Comment: To add on to this answer: it is most likely that the order of imports at the top of your .go file that is incorrect, although the `gci` tool doesn't actually tell you this in the error message. If you don't want to install `gci` locally, try reordering your imports and see if clears the error.